# Stuck on "verification fail" while Rooting Moto G 3rd gen

Tags: rooting, root-access, motorola-moto-g, superuser

I am trying to root my moto g 3rd gen.

I am following this guide:
http://theunlockr.com/2015/09/09/how-to-root-the-motorola-moto-g-3rd-gen/

I am completely stuck on Step 7: installing SuperSu on the device.

**What I did:**

- Unlock booting
- Start via command `adb reboot recovery`
- Get past no command screen
- select zip browsing the file system
- push the zip using the command: `adb sideload C:\...etc\...zip`

**The Zip I am using is this one:**

https://download.chainfire.eu/696/SuperSU/UPDATE-SuperSU-v2.46.zip

**The Result:**

```
Finding update package...
Opening update package...
Verifying update package...
E: failed to verify whole-file signature
E: signature verification failed
Installation aborted
```

What can I do from here? Are there better ways to root this particular device? How do I get around this error?

Comment: I have TWRP, as described in the guide. Yes, reboot.

Comment: Alright, so first copy your SuperSU zip into phone. You can use `adb push` or MTP or anything that suits you. Then in TWRP, select Install -> locate the zip file you just moved and proceed with flash. Done.

Comment: That's what I did, but I get this verification error.

Comment: But you did `adb sideload` but I said something else. Okay, hold on.

Comment: I tried both. Selecting zip and after that failed sidemount via cmd.

Comment: Under Settings of TWRP, see if "Zip file Signature verification" is unchecked or not. If checked, uncheck it and then try.

Comment: I don't see any checkboxes, its all text based. Where do I find this checkbox?

Comment: When you boot into TWRP, you will see some boxes with shape of a SIM card and labels like Install, Wipe, Backup.. Among them is a box named Settings. Under it, you would see a list of options. There should be that option about verification.

Comment: I think I am failing at the previos step. Nowhere does it actually say TWERP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems Moto G 3rd Gen is **very tricky** to root. I spent 2 days trying countless things and having countless problems every step of the way. I drove myself insane with it, however at the end, it worked and my Moto G 3rd Gen is rooted now.

For everyone else experiencing problems with rooting this device here is some info on what to do:

**1. Bootloader Unlock**

This first step of the process is already pretty tricky.

To achive it you need to closely follow the steps on this page:
https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/standalone/bootloader/unlock-your-device-a

Keep in mind:

The instructions on this page are potentionally (perhaps intentionally) misleading as to trip up unexperienced users. Some things to keep in mind:

1. on Win CMD you don't actually need to type the $ chars displayed in the instructons on this page. Its best to read some basics about handling cmd before doing this, like how to navigate in cmd.
2. you need to install Android SDK and JAVA and than run the program ADB in CMD prompt using admin. This is the path: C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb
3. You need to install USB drivers. You can find Moto G 3rd Gen Drivers here: https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/88481
4. You need to enable Developer Options on your device by tapping 9 times on "about this phone" in settings.
5. You need to enable OEM unlocking in developer options.
6. You need to enable USB debugging in developer options.
7. You need to be logged in in Motorolla Care in order to get a key, you will need to unlock bootloader, otherwise the form returns a 500.

   **2. Installing TWRP**

This step is what ultimately tripped me up. The trick here is, that after installation of TWRP the system restores the old recovery program you want to replace and you always return to square one.

In order to make this one work we need to apply a little bit of trickery.

1. Download TWRP img file and put it somewhere in your windows filesystem
2. Connect your Moto G with USB and start adb in cmd as admin
3. execute this command: `adb reboot bootloader`
4. When the phone reboots into bootloader mode, execute this: `fastboot flash recovery recovery.img` make sure to replace "recovery.img" with the path to your file and the right name of the file. After this one is done, the next step is crucial, otherwise all progress will be lost.
5. Remove your USB cable from the phone
6. Boot straight into recovery without any reboots. To do use the volume keys to select booting mode, select with power button.
7. You should boot into TWRP interface, which is a touch interface with rectangles to click on. If you land on "no command" screen or "system recovery" DOS style screen, you probably need to repeat the installation of TWRP and try to avoid it being automatically replaced / restored to default by the system (this seems to be happening on reboot).
8. In TWRP click Install. Choose SuperSu.zip from your phone file system and install it. Once this is all finished reboot your device, it should be rooted. Use root checker app to check your root status.

Useful tutorial:
http://theunlockr.com/2015/09/09/how-to-root-the-motorola-moto-g-3rd-gen/

Only problem with this tutorial is, it doesn't mention that TWRP will be deleted by the system if you reboot. So you need to adjust that part of the tutorial as described here.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that TWRP will be replaced upon reboot. This is also true on my Galaxy Note 4. I used ODIN (specific to Samsung) and disabled the 'auto-reboot' option. After booting right into recovery from there I finally managed to root my device. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 1):

I totally understand the situation here as *I just faced it and came out from it.*

The think is simple!

Note many devices will replace your custom recovery automatically during first boot. To prevent this, use Google to find the proper key combo to enter recovery. After typing **fastboot reboot**, hold the key combo and boot to TWRP. Once TWRP is booted, TWRP will patch the stock ROM to prevent the stock ROM from replacing TWRP. If you don't follow this step, you will have to repeat the install.

[This is the official twrp site which you should consider](http://teamw.in/devices/androidone.html)

Read the above link carefully. Note again that you must click the key combo before your android recovery boots, otherwise you have to install the recovery again and again.

Hope I cleared your doubt. Thanks all.